# Google Map does not render in Android App

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to load a Google Map inside a view on an Android application. The view displays an empty map as shown below:

[image: Image of view attempting to display a map]

Below is a look at my code:

**The FragmentController**

```
public class LookFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private View rootView;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private MapView mMapView;
    MarkerOptions place1, place2;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_have_a_look, container, false);

        String[] countries = new String[] {"Roadwork", "Current Incident"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(
                        getContext(),
                        R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item,
                        countries);

        AutoCompleteTextView editTextFilledExposedDropdown = root.findViewById(R.id.have_a_look_filter_field);
        editTextFilledExposedDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

        try{
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.have_a_look_map_view);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }catch (InflateException e){
            Log.e("TAG", "Inflate exception");
        }

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(52.930535,-0.046874)).title("Location 1");
        place2 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(52.927879, -0.052469)).title("Location 2");

        map.addMarker(place1);
        map.addMarker(place2);

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(52.930535,-0.046874)));
    }

}
```

**The Fragment inside the View**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/have_a_look_map_view"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/have_a_look_search_layout" />
```

**The AndroidManifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="www.aidanm.trafficscotland">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat Output**

```
03/06 12:08:16: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3 API 29.
$ adb shell am start -n "www.aidanm.trafficscotland/www.aidanm.trafficscotland.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: www.aidanm.trafficscotland.test | www.aidanm.trafficscotland
Waiting for application to come online: www.aidanm.trafficscotland.test | www.aidanm.trafficscotland
Waiting for application to come online: www.aidanm.trafficscotland.test | www.aidanm.trafficscotland
Connecting to www.aidanm.trafficscotland
Waiting for application to start debug server
Waiting for application to come online: www.aidanm.trafficscotland.test | www.aidanm.trafficscotland
Connecting to www.aidanm.trafficscotland
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10148(www.aidanm.trafficscotland) identical 1 line
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1428)
I/trafficscotlan: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:256): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=5953 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c148,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mAccessibilityDelegate:Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe118e180, tid 15452
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf797f520: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf797f520: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf7989b70)
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xcd3f1180, tid 15452
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff706000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf797f520: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf7989b70)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
W/trafficscotlan: Unsupported class loader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:222
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 222
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 200414040
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeInt(JIZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekInt(JZ)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayIndexScale(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xcd3f2670, tid 15487
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe111ee20: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe111ee20: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xcd1b21a0)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1409ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=94683831255201, Vsync=94685081255151, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=94685084503140, AnimationStart=94685084598140, PerformTraversalsStart=94685086519140, DrawStart=94685181584140, SyncQueued=94685212145140, SyncStart=94685213087140, IssueDrawCommandsStart=94685213868140, SwapBuffers=94685237122140, FrameCompleted=94685241560140, DequeueBufferDuration=95000, QueueBufferDuration=1264000, 
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/trafficscotlan: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

**What I Have Tried**

Changing the API key for different privileges:

- Using an unrestricted key
- Using a key only the maps APIS
- Signing the app in the Keystore and copying the SHA

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't help most users, but I have found the reason why it wouldn't work. Turns out the network I was connected to was blocking all access to the google maps service. Rookie error but remember to try changing networks to see if that's the problem.